# Passing a pointer to array of string pointers

Tags: c

In the example below if I uncomment the printing of matches[1] and matches[2] in the print_and_modify function it fails(Illegal instruction: 4 on my Mac OS X mavericks).

What confuses me is why matches[0] works fine ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_and_modify(char ***matches) {
  printf("%s\n", *matches[0]);
  /* printf("%s\n", *matches[1]); */
  /* printf("%s", *matches[2]); */
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  char **matches;

  matches = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));

  matches[0] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
  matches[1] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
  matches[2] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));

  char *test1 = "test1";
  char *test2 = "test2";
  char *test3 = "test3";

  strncpy(matches[0],test1,5);
  strncpy(matches[1],test2,5);
  strncpy(matches[2],test3,5);
  print_and_modify(&matches);

  printf("======\n");
  printf("%s\n", matches[0]);
  printf("%s\n", matches[1]);
  printf("%s\n", matches[2]);
}
```

*Please excuse the contrived example. I am trying to learn some C.*

Comment: If you're learning C, as soon as you see `***` RUN AWAY.

Comment: How else would you pass a pointer to a *char[] to a function ?

Comment: use `(*matches)[0]`,`(*matches)[1]`and `(*matches)[2]` instead of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's operator precedence: `[]` has higher precedence than `*`, so you need to force the desired precedence:

```
void print_and_modify(char ***matches) {
    printf("%s\n", (*matches)[0]);
    printf("%s\n", (*matches)[1]);
    printf("%s", (*matches)[2]);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/YSSEuL)

Note that you do not need to pass a triple pointer, unless you wish to modify the allocated array itself. If you pass a double pointer, you would be able to modify the content of the individual strings, and also replace strings with other strings by de-allocating or re-allocating the char arrays.

Comment: `[]` is called subscript, `*` is called dereference.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I do plan to modify the allocated array. I would like for the function to be able to increase the size of the array. Additionally I would also like for print_and_modify to be able to initialize it if its not been initialized yet. Thanks for the help!